# Excel VBA - Using shapes as toggle buttons

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a shape instead of a button to toggle hiding rows with blank cells (according to conditions). Is it even possible?

```
Sub ToggleChevron3_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:C100")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With rng
            For Each cell In rng                              
                    If cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = "" Then      ' Condition 1
                       If cell.Value = "" Then                ' Condition 2
                          ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chevron 3").cell.EntireRow.Hidden _
                         = Not ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chevron 3").cell.EntireRow.Hidden
                       End If
                    End If
            Next
        End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The code to accomplish what I think you are looking for is below. Both pieces of code below assume you want to just click a button to hide / unhide the rows, depending on the current state.

```
Sub ToggleChevron3_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
'Set rng = Range("A1:C100") 'do you really want to loop through every cell in columns A through C
Set rng = Range("A1:A100")

For Each cell In rng

    If Len(cell.Offset(, 4).Value) = 0 And Len(cell.Value) = 0 Then

        Dim bToggle As Boolean
        bToggle = cell.EntireRow.Hidden

        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = Not bToggle

    End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

However, there is **alternative** that is cleaner code and faster execution, as long as filtering is okay for you.

```
Sub ToggleChevron3_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim bToggle As Boolean

bToggle = ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode

If bToggle Then

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

Else

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:E100") 'used E because you had an offset of 4 columns

    With rng
        .AutoFilter 5, "<>"
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>"
    End With

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for the solution as well as the alternative. Excuse my two part question, but is it possible to use a shape as on/off toggle?

Comment: If you really want to use shapes, you can do it one of two ways. 1) Add another shape and put code behind it to unhide the rows in (or unfilter) the range. 2) Place some kind of trigger in a cell or textbox that triggers if it's on or off when you click the shape.

Comment: Ignore my last comment. I reflected more on what you were asking and understood it better. I am editing my answer to update the code to Toggle it back and forth based on just clicking the button.